# Akka Actor (Scala) app running inside a docker container restarts without any error being shown in logs

Tags: scala, docker, akka

I have an Akka actor application running in Docker which appears to be causing the container to restart without throwing any exception or error that is captured in the logs.

How could I find out what is causing the container to restart itself?

No other containers on the host machine are affected (judging by their uptimes)

EDIT:
Dockerfile used:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim

ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

WORKDIR /opt

RUN mkdir /opt/logs
COPY path/to/target/application.jar /opt/application.jar

CMD ["java", "-server", "-jar", "application.jar", "--configPath", "./application.conf"]
```

Comment: How do you create the docker image? Can you post the Dockerfile?

Comment: @Felipe added the Dockerfile but there's not much going on in there

Comment: Do you copy `application.conf` to the image?

What does your application do? Maybe it's the app that exits?

Comment: did you tried to use sbt-native-packager with docker plugin? it provide a good documentation for docker apps

Comment: @amorfis - the conf is mapped in as a volume

Comment: @SourceCodeBot The project is a maven project so not sure I can use the sbt-native-packager. 

The application reads off a message broker, transforms data, writes to MySQL. It's been running for almost 18 months but has only recently been having this issue in production. The container restarts randomly every 1-3 days when there is traffic. So, I'm trying to find ways to track down what causes the restart. Application logs show no errors just normal debug logs and then suddenly restart.

Comment: It is hard to say if you state that no exception is on the log. Either you add some methods to inspect logs from Akka or maybe there is some part of the code that is hiding exceptions. Or there is anothe log erros from the containers.

Comment: may you add a logback configuration to log everything to a mounted path and check this logs for any kind of exception. also, use akka.loglevel ="DEBUG" to check akkas internal log messages too